# Запись звука. Реализация на С#

Tags: c#, аудио, directx

Доброго Времени суток!
Пишу некий проект. Необходимо записывать звук через микрофон.
Нашел в интернете три проекта, как это сделать...

[CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31356/C-MP3-Sound-Capturing-Recording-Component)
[cyberforum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread63829.html) Два здесь.

Все заявляют что и них эта программа работает... У меня откомпилировался только тот проект, который написан на С++.
Когда я питался запустить Дебагер на MicrosoftVS То вылетела ошибка:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [pelmeshka80.d9x.ru](http://www.pelmeshka80.d9x.ru/Untitled-2.jpg))</sub>

У меня Windows7 на ноуте...
Методом проб и ошибок я понял что такое наблюдается при использовании библиотеки

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста решение данной проблемы!
Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, стоит установить последнюю версию DirectX Managed API и поэкспериментировать со архитектурой сборки проекта (32 и 64 бита). Для начала попробуй явно указать x86.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ спас мой проект) Плюсую!
Спасла фраза "для начала попробуй явно указать х86."

Answer (score 1):

Microsft DirectX SDK -> download -> install